# variable in bash not working

Tags: bash, curl, local-variables

I have a simple function in my bashrc file, it takes 2 arguments and makes a curl call. The problem is, the curl request is not getting the variable. Here's the function...

```
checkUserName() {
    cd ~/
    echo "checking for username $2"
    curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"userName": "$2"}' http://localhost:8080/$1/verify
}
alias unameCheck=checkUserName
```

Then I call it with something like...

```
unameCheck users danwguy
```

and I will see...

```
checking for username danwguy
```

in my terminal prompt, however when I look at my logs from my application it shows that it is checking for userName $2
So the variable isn't being replaced in the curl command, even though the $1 is being replaced, since it is calling the correct API on my localhost.
It replaces it in the echo command, but not in the curl command.

I have even tried creating a local variable, but that still doesn't work, no matter what I do, it doesn't replace in the curl call, but it does in the echo call. 
Can anyone see why it wouldn't be properly replacing the $2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter expansions (`$var`) will not expand in single quotes. Use double quotes instead:

```
$ curl -w "@curl-format.txt" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    -d '{"userName": "'"$2"'"}' \
    "http://localhost:8080/$1/verify"
```

Also wrap parameter expansions in double quotes to avoid [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and
[pathname expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs).

Comment: Good answer; terminology quibble: `$var` is a _reference to a parameter_ (variable). Recognizing that reference and replacing it with the parameter's value is what's called _parameter expansion_.
Similarly, you avoid _unquoted references_ to parameters (or unquoted command substitutions / arithmetic expansions) to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note to previous comment.

You can escape double quotes with backslash, to tell bash interpreter  to not interpret its special meaning, so final code looks like:

```
... -d "{\"userName\": \"$2\"}"  ...
```

Which is way more obvious for me...